# What are the level names in Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

I was playing a game the other night and saw someone with the rank of "Rocketeer." Before that I had assumed that Rookie, Semi-Pro, Pro, and Veteran were the only ranks. How does one achieve the rank of Rocketeer?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The titles are currently (as of the 1.50 update) earned at:

- 20: Veteran
- 40: Expert
- 60: Master
- 80: Legend
- 100: Rocketeer

In addition to this, new titles will be available every 100 levels.

[Source](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/patch-notes-v1-50-progression-update/)

Comment: For some reason, this answer keeps getting edited with incorrect information. Reviewers: please make sure the information is correct before accepting an edit.